# Shiv'a Asar Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred seventeen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 217 *betzim* in a *s'ah* of *Nausa*. Source: [*Eruvin* 83:1](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=600).

Answer (score 1):

Outside Eretz Yisroel - from the start of Succos till the end of Simchas Torah is approximately 217 hours.

9 x 24 + 1 = 217

Answer (score 0):

אורי    =    217

Comment: Upvote because down is a degradation. These posts connect dots literally years later.

Answer (score 0):

217 = דבורה Deborah the prophetous or "bee(s)"